# Tool to auto-set settings like main display & energy options

Tags: windows, control-panel

Is there a way to auto set (semi-automatic) some settings in Windows 10, because when I use my Laptop at home, I only want to use my external monitor, not the laptop's monitor; also, by default, it goes to energy saving mode when closed: this can also be changed via the Control Panel. After some time it gets quite annoying to click though the Control Panel one by one, so I would like to have a tool where one just has to press a button or something to do those things.

Comment: @Psycogeek Alright, switching the power profile in cmd works; any idea on how to do a similar thing to set screen settings (duplicate display, extend display, only show desktop on 1/2)?

Comment: @Psycogeek, you can just do powercfg -l (-list) to get a list of schemes. The entire query thingy was for windows 2003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Easy way to switch power plan in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/957500/easy-way-to-switch-power-plan-in-windows-10/957520#957520) This question has good full answers to the how to swap a power plan in windows 10.

WIN-P brings up "extend/duplicate monitor" side charm bar , which allows you to quickly configure a couple of monitors or projectors.