# Power plans disappeared after Windows 10 Fall update (1709)

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, power-management, windows-10-v1709

**UPDATE:** I went back to 1703.
See source: [New power options in Windows 10](http://www.rawinfopages.com/tips/2017/08/new-power-options-in-windows-10/)

Listing power plans using `powercfg` shows only the Balanced one.

[image]

And that's the registry situation:

[image]

And the power schemes, which seems fine:

[image]

What happend here?

Comment: Did you already double-check to ensure that the video card driver is still working properly, and that is hasn't reverted to `Standard VGA Graphics Adapter` after the update?

Comment: @Run5k yes absolutely. The driver is still there (the dGPU is a Nvidia GTX 1050)

Comment: I wondered why the Power Saver and Performance plans disappeared when I updated to the latest Slow Ring build... My custom power plans didn't disappear however, and when you go to create a new power plan, you can still select the Power Saver and Performance power plans as templates.

Comment: @Sonickyle27 seems Windows now want us to manage everything from the battery slider popup. What a mess. Going back to 1703

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1261306/cant-change-powerplan-settings-in-windows-10-build-v1709

Comment: @LPChip hey, post it as an answer so people will see it immediatly!

Comment: @LPChip btw my TDP setting is not honored with custom power plans in Windows 10 1709.

Comment: I honestly don’t care which question is the duplicate.

Comment: @Ramhound me neither. The matter is if a question goes as "duplicate" people don't even bother to read possible (future) edits or comments, they just jump to the other one, which may be incomplete.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answer copied from: [Can't change powerplan settings in Windows 10 build v1709](https://superuser.com/questions/1261306/cant-change-powerplan-settings-in-windows-10-build-v1709)

The powersettings dialog itself has not been changed, but the upgrade removed all powerplan settings but the Balanced one, and it will remember the setting currently in use.

If you switch to the balanced one, your old one will be forgotten too.

In order to get them back, you need to create a new powerplan first, mark one of the 3 templates and give them a name. For example, if you want to use the default High Performance powerplan, you first have to create it before you can switch to it.

Comment: It's worth adding that the balanced power plan appears to have settings where it's possible to change between battery saving and high performance and balanced (https://i.imgur.com/EFaOQyr.png). Could be that the high performance power plan has been replaced with the balanced one, and that it's designed to handle both of the modes

Comment: @Zoe but that only works on laptops, not on pc's.

Answer (score 30):

If you right-click on the battery symbol in Systray and start Mobility Center you can still se three power plans in the combo box and select one.

Comment: This answer is extremely helpful! By bringing up Windows Mobility Center I was able to switch to High Performance power plan, which then immediately showed up in the Power Options control panel. Even if I make edits to the High Performance plan, and then switch back to balance, my edits are preserved when I restore the High Performance plan again. Thank you!

Comment: For me there's only Balanced too.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! After I switched plans there, all of them suddenly appear in “Choose a power plan”, where they should have been shown in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/only-1-default-power-plan-windows-10/2d9463d7-3be4-46a4-a902-b13a125520f6:

> Open the registry editor.  If you don't know how, open search/Cortana
>   and type `regedit`.
>
> Using the folders on the left hand side, navigate to the following
>   folder: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power` on
>   the right, one of the keys near the top should be called `CsEnabled`. Click on this.
>
> Change the value of this key from `1` to `0`.
>
> After you reboot you should have your power plans back.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Nope I tried this and rebooted and it doesn't work.

Comment: Worked on my Dell (Windows Pro 1909 build 18363.720).

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Open a command prompt.
> 2. Copy and paste the command below for the missing power plan you want to restore into the command prompt, and press Enter.
>
> **(Power saver)**
>   `powercfg -duplicatescheme a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a`
>
> **(Balanced)**
>   `powercfg -duplicatescheme 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e`
>
> **(High Performance)**
>   `powercfg -duplicatescheme 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c`
>
> **(Ultimate Performance - Windows 10 build 17101 and later)**
>   `powercfg -duplicatescheme e9a42b02-d5df-448d-aa00-03f14749eb61`
>
> 3. You can now close the command prompt if you like.

Source: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/110372-restore-missing-default-power-plans-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Did not work on my computer (Windows Pro 1909 build 18363.720).

Answer (score -2):

There's no different power plans after falls creators, you have to choose the type of performance you want, for that, just left click the battery icon in systray and ajust it.