# Can't change powerplan settings in Windows 10 build v1709

Tags: windows-10-v1709

After upgrading my windows 10, I can no longer change powersettings. It only says the one I use and Balanced.

Where has the setting to change power plan settings moved to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The powersettings dialog itself has not been changed, but the upgrade removed all powerplan settings but the Balanced one, and it will remember the setting currently in use.

If you switch to the balanced one, your old one will be forgotten too.

In order to get them back, you need to create a new powerplan first, mark one of the 3 templates and give them a name. For example, if you want to use the default High Performance powerplan, you first have to create it before you can switch to it.

EDIT: It appears to be a bug in the upgrading process. A fresh install of windows 10 does have the default powerplan settings available.

EDIT2: Its worse than I thought. Apparently a bug in the windows 10 installer sometimes does manage the powerplan settings, sometimes it doesn't. I bet the upgrade has the similar problem. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I did a fresh install where the powerplan settings were removed, had this twice now.

Comment: Until this is not fixed I will stay on 1703. Also, as I said back last month, the TDP setting is never respected for my i7