# Creating a Windows Power Plan that can be restored to default

Tags: windows, powercfg

I am interested in creating a custom power plan to deploy with our customer's PCs to save them some configuration steps. Creating the custom plan and importing/exporting is no problem, however the custom plan lacks the ability to be restored to default settings.

All of the standard Windows plans (Balanced, High Performance, and Power Saver) have this restore feature. In addition on our DELL PCs, there exists a DELL power plan which is also able to be restored. This means there must be some way to install a custom plan that also has the "restore to default" feature. Does anyone have any idea how it is possible to create a custom power plan that is able to be restored?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but as a work-around you can export the Registry key `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings` with all subkeys, or just those for the default, and include that in the customer setup.

[You can also script the command line tool powercfg.exe](https://superuser.com/questions/957500/easy-way-to-switch-power-plan-in-windows-10) to set the active scheme:
`powercfg /s powwerschemeGUID`.