# How to trigger Windows 10's battery saver when lid's closed or after a certain time

Tags: windows, laptop, battery, autohotkey

I was wondering if it would be possible to turn on the Windows 10's battery saver (the one you can enable when clicking the battery icon on the taskbar) when the lid is closed (also locking the PC) or after, say, 2 minutes of inactivity pass.
I  did some research and found no answer to my question.
I was thinking of the task scheduler, AutoHotkey or registry hacking, but, again, there's no info on how to trigger these events.
Perhaps you have some idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've written an answer in the past that does exactly this. Let me find it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easy way to switch power plan in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/957500/easy-way-to-switch-power-plan-in-windows-10)

Comment: Note, I explain the steps to create a .cmd file for switching. You can use this command or the .cmd file itself in Task Scheduler and hook it on event On lid close and On lid open.

Comment: This looks very promising, thanks! I was thinking of triggering the Windows 10's battery saver, not the legacy one, since I only have one energy plan there (balanced). I'm not quite sure if the legacy power settings work for the newer features, like the UWP apps. Do you perhaps have an idea on how to trigger the new battery saver? Much appreciated!

Comment: Just create a new plan, and set it up in there. I believe that once you make a new power plan, you can go into the Windows 10 battery safer and adjust the settings for that power plan, so they retain their settings when you switch. But what I did was limit my entire CPU speed in the plan itself and power consumption went down from 200watt to a mere 10 watt, and the computer was still usable.